# Add attribute without value to Blazor component depending on other attribute value

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have this custom component

```
<label class="btn-svg label-wrapper">
    @Title

    @if (Multiple)
    {
        <InputFile OnChange="@InputFileOnChange" class="custom-input-hide" accept="@FileFilter" multiple/>
    }
    else
    {
        <InputFile OnChange="@InputFileOnChange" class="custom-input-hide" accept="@FileFilter"/>
    }
</label>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string FileFilter { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Multiple { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<InputFileChangeEventArgs> InputFileOnChange { get; set; }

}
```

How can I rework `@if (Multiple)` part and add `multiple` parameter similarly to `OnChange="@InputFileOnChange"` ?

I tried to add `@Multiple` string parameter inside InputFile.
Like this
`<InputFile OnChange="@InputFileOnChange" class="custom-input-hide" accept="@FileFilter" @Multiple/>`

But then component is not rendering with error - `Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@Multiple' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: `InputFile` doesn’t have an explicit `Multiple` attribute, so that error is expected. It just passes through unrecognised attributes to the `input` HTML tag. The way you have it with the `if` seems fine.

Comment: I believe for non-value flags like `selected` and possibly `multiple`, Blazor will render x='true' as x.  Possibly try `<InputFile OnChange="@InputFileOnChange" class="custom-input-hide" accept="@FileFilter" multiple=@Multiple/>` I'm quite sure this is the case for `selected`, but not sure if all similar tags are treated like that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#conditional-html-element-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```html
<InputFile ... multiple="@Multiple" />
```

When `@Multiple` is `false` Blazor will remove the 'multiple' attribute, when it is true it will result in just `multiple` in the HTML, without the `=` .

It works the same for `hidden`, `disabled` etc.